# what is the right name of PostgreSQL adapter for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

This is my `db/config.yml` file:

```
adapter: postgres
server: localhost
etc.
```

When I'm using `rake db:migrate` it works with `adapter: postgresql`. Otherwise it complains:

```
Please install the postgres adapter: gem install activerecord-postgres-adapter
```

When I'm using `sequel` with `Sequel.connect(YAML.load_file(..))` it works with `adapter: postgres`. Otherwise it complains:

```
Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/postgresql
```

What to do? :)

Answer (score 2):

With Sequel you have to use `postgres`.  Apparently ActiveRecord requires `postgresql`.  They are different tools, you shouldn't expect the same configuration file to work on both.